# Call method when dynamic element is in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use `$http` service to get data and generate DOM elements.
How can I in `jQuery/AngularJS` call a method (example .`slideToggle()`) on dynamic element? I need to do this when page is loaded (not on click event etc.).

To do this one `$('#test').slideToggle()` (#test is generated element) i need use timeout.

Comment: *"on dynamic element? I need to do this when page is loaded (not on click event etc.)."* Well, is it dynamic (added after page load), or do you need to do it on page load?

Comment: The basic answer is: Whatever it is that's loading the element, should then do the `slideToggle` on it once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for sure from your description, but if you're creating the element from data you retrieve remotely, you should ensure that element's creation/insertion are completed before you attempt to scroll to it.

The following code is an example of how you may do this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
})
.then(createAndInsertYourElement)
.then(scrollToElem);

function createAndInsertYourElement(data) {
    var $elem = $('<div id="test">' + data.whateva + '</div>');
    $('#someElement').append($elem);
    return $elem;
}

function scrollToElem($elem) {
    $elem.slideToggle();
}
```

Note the `.then`s.  These are an option because Angular's $http returns a promise.  If you're not familiar with promises, yet, they are awesome, and you should check 'em out: http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/